# How do I create a div in html which is absolutely positioned, which will push other elements to the side like in Apple's Pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

How do I create a div which will act like a relatively positioned div (as in it cannot allow elements behind it) and still will also act like an absolutely positioned div (as in it can freely be positioned)? I am willing to use javascript and jQuery if needed.

Example: [image: Example] or a similar effect

Comment: I can't picture what your trying to do...Any examples or code?

Comment: No, like I have an absolutely positioned image, which is covering the textarea underneath. I know I can use `padding-top`, but I don't know the exact size of the image as the size of the image varies, so I wanted to make the image like that, so that it will 'push' the other elements to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you're asking for in the way you're asking for it.  You should be able to fake it adequately though.

Say you wanted to "insert" a sidebar that pushes all the main content on a page over by 200 pixels (the width of the sidebar).  You could increase the left margin of the page/container by 200px (animate it if you wanna be flashy) and then absolutely position your div where you want it (you could animate it sliding in from off screen if you want it to appear as if it is "pushing" the other content over).  If I understood the question correctly, then this should accomplish the visual effect you're going for.

Comment: I just saw your comment noting that you're not always sure of the size of your image - that get's a little trickier.  You can use jQuery (or another lib) to determine the size of your element to make sure that your moving things over enough.  I've had mixed success with size queries on rendered elements, but I can't imagine an image reporting weird sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Draggable elements, you can use jQuery User Interface:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/